# WebStorm 2016.1 TypeScript "Cannot start compiler process"

Tags: macos, typescript, webstorm

I've just installed JetBrains WebStorm 2016.1.1 Build #WS-145.597 for evaluation on OS X latest.

I want to use TypeScript but there is an immediate problem: I have enabled the TypeScript compiler in settings but in the Typescript Compiler tool window is complaining that it "Cannot start compiler process".

I've noticed that the build date on the WebStorm About box was yesterday (March 30 2016) so this may be a recently introduced issue.

Is anyone else having this problem? Anyone got an idea how to sort it?

Comment: I reported this issue here, please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23344

Comment: Thanks to @uloco, this is expected to be fixed in 2016.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to specify a node interpreter in the typescript settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @anstarovoyt that did the trick.  The requirement could be better signposted - I won't be using Node.js any time soon.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the TypeScript compiler alone didn't solve this for IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 on Linux. I had to go back through my older project that didn't have the problem to find the solution.

After setting up your typescript compiler below.
[image: TypeScript Compiler Settings]

I then had to directly edit this same setting within my project's .idea directory. Within your project structure, navigate to your .idea directory then locate and open file typescript-compiler.xml like below.
[image: Direct Edit]

Now add the following xml option element after the "useConfig" option element:

```
<option name="nodeInterpreterTextField" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../../node/bin/node" />
```

Be sure to change the directory path to your instance of node.
[image: Fixed]

Sadly, this solution we be overridden every time you edit and save your settings. IDEA will have to fix their bug for a lasting solution.

Comment: Thx, had the same problem under Windows! Was this problem already reported to IntelliJ

Comment: Under IntelliJ Version 2016.2.3